# Evenly pruning an ordered set

Tags: algorithm

Given an ordered set of n elements (a1, a2, ..., an), what algorithm can I use to pick M of these elements (M < n) such that the sampling from the original set is as spread out as possible?

For example, if the starting set is the numbers from 1 to 9 (i.e. n=9), and I want to evenly sample it so I end up with only 5 of those numbers (i.e. M=9), I'd select 1, 3, 5, 7, 9. To get 3 of the original 9, I'd go with 1, 5, 9, and so on. But what would the pseudo-code for picking the elements look like for any n and M?

The mathematical formulation for this problem would be as follows: given M < n, find the set q(1), q(2), ..., q(M) such that 1 <= q(k) < q(k+1) <= M for any k:[1, M-1], and the sum of q(k+1)-q(k) for k: [1, M-1] is the maximum possible.

Comment: Your sum is maximum if you choose q1 = a1 and qM = an. The numbers in between do not matter because their respective terms cancel out. Do you instead want to maximize the minimum difference?

Comment: Do you want to evenly space the indices (i.e. you picked 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 because the difference is exactly 2 for all of them)? Or evenly space the values (i.e. you picked 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 because a9 - a7 = a7 - a5 = a5 - a3 = a3 - a1, or as close to that as possible)?

Answer (score 0):

Following Nico's suggestion of maximizing the minimum difference (the form of the objective function is fairly flexible), there's a simple **O(n^2 M)-time** dynamic program that goes something like this.

```
def prune(a, M):
    n = len(a)
    # The [i][j] entry is the max min gap
    # for a[0], ..., a[i] choose j + 1 (a[0] is always chosen).
    table = [[float('inf')] * M for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(M):
            table[i][j] = max(min(table[k][j], a[i] - a[k])
                              for k in range(i))
    # Trace back the sequence of argmaxes to recover the chosen indexes.
```

This can be improved to **O(n M) time** using total monotonicity. The idea is that, as `i` increases, the proper value for `k` can only increase too, and as soon as the objective decreases when we increase `k`, we can move on to the next `i`.

Both of the above algorithms handle fairly general objectives. If max is OK, then there's an **O(n log n)-time** algorithm that uses binary search to guess the minimum gap and then check whether it's feasible. I'll wait for you to update the question.